# How Can I Manually Add Connections to Groups with Multiple Hubs in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have two hubs, call them `NotificationHub` and `ReminderHub`. Think of `NotificationHub` as the main hub, and `ReminderHub` as an optional hub that I wish to separate from `NotificationHub`. Clients will connect to `NotificationHub` with the following typical server hub method.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    return base.OnConnected()
}
```

with corresponding client connection

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    subscribeToReminderHub();
});
```

`subscribeToReminderHub();` contains the following

```
subscribeToReminderHub = function() {
    reminderProxy = $.connection.reminderHub;

    reminderProxy.server.subscribe().done(function() {
        console.log('subscribed to reminder hub...');
    });
}
```

`reminderProxy.server.subscribe()` refers to the following server method on `ReminderHub`

```
public async Task Subscribe()
{
    var currentUser = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToUpperInvariant();
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, currentUser);
}
```

This all works as I would tyically expect. I can hit a break point on the server `Subscribe()` method, as well as log out

> *subscribed to reminder hub...*

However, if I try to then invoke methods on users in the groupings I am trying to establish in `ReminderHub`, nothing will occur. I have defined two client functions inside my initial connection `.done()` callback. Consider the following example

```
public void Notify() // ... ReminderHub
{
    // ***** notification chain - step 2
    // ***** this never gets called
    var userId = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToUpperInvariant();
    Clients.Caller.notify();
}
```

---

```
// **** $.connection.hub.start().done(function() { **** callback
subscribeToReminderHub = function() {
    reminderProxy = $.connection.reminderHub;

    reminderProxy.server.subscribe().done(function() {
        console.log('subscribed to reminder hub...');
    });

    reminderProxy.client.queryNotifications = function () {
        // ***** notification chain - step 1
        // ***** this never gets called
        reminderProxy.server.notify();
    }

    reminderProxy.client.notify = function () {
        // ***** notification chain - step 3
        // ***** this never gets called
    }
}
```

Starting this notification chain, I am invoking `Notify()` external from the hub like... note: I am passing `userId` which would relate back to the grouping

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ReminderHub>().Clients.Group(userId).queryNotifications();
```

### The most interesting part of this whole issue

is that if I don't introduce a second hub, and establish the group on `NotificationHub`'s `OnConnected` and re-factor all logic back to the sole hub, this entire process works as expected. Somehow introducing a second hub and trying to establish a group outside of `OnConnected` is not working. Has anyone experienced this? Thoughts?

### Even more interesting! (and awful!)

if I open up my browser dev tools and explicitly paste the following into my console

> `reminderProxy.server.notify()`

I hit the breakpoint on `ReminderHub`'s `Notify()`!
I continue through `Clients.Caller.notify();` and the client function `.notify()` does not even get called in my client JS. I can't understand that at all. Bypassing all groping concerns, I can't even hit a client function now that I've introduced `ReminderHub`

Comment: I use multiple hubs and I normally have no issues. From what you say I'd check 2 things: 1. are you 100% sure the `userId` you use with the hub context is correct? 2. did you setup all your client side event handlers *before* starting the connection?

Comment: @Wasp setting up client events before connection-sheer brilliance. This was my exact problem. I was trying to define these additional functions in the `.done()` callback of my connection. If you craft up a succinct answer for this I'll gladly accept

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll craft it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure you prepare all of your client-side event handlers before starting the connection, otherwise SignalR will not fulfill them (at least in its current version).